# Invalid character error in my cantilever static program

Tags: fortran

I am trying to make a program about a cantilever arm.

```
program statik

    implicit none 
    integer :: i;
    real :: x, stuetzlaenge, belastung, einzellastlaenge, einzellast, auflagerkraft, querkraft, moment;
    logical :: debugging

    debugging = .false. 

    if (debugging) then
        stuetzlaenge = 1.0
        belastung = 1.0
    else
        print *, 'Statik: Kragarm unter Gleichlast mit Einzellast an beliebiger Stelle'
        print *, 'Bitte geben Sie die Geometrie und die Belastungen ein: '
        write(*,100) '- Stuetzlaenge  l [m] = '
        read(*,*) stuetzlaenge
        write(*,100) '- Gleichlast q [kN/m] = '
        read(*,*) belastung
        write(*,100) '- Lage der Einzellast a [m] = '
        read(*,*) einzellastlaenge
        write(*,100) '- Einzellast F [kN] = ' 
        read(*,*) einzellast
    end if

    print *, 'Eingaben:'
    print *, '- Stuetzlaenge  l [m] = ', stuetzlaenge
    print *, '- Gleichlast q [kN/m] = ', belastung
    print *, '- Lage der Einzellast a [m] = ', einzellastlaenge
    print *, '- Einzellast F [kN] = ', einzellast

    print *, 'Ergebnisse:'
    auflagerkraft = belastung*stuetzlaenge + einzellast;
    print *, '- Auflagerkraft: A = ', auflagerkraft , ' kN'
    print *, '- Querkraefte:'
    do i = 0, 10
        x = stuetzlaenge*i/10 [m];
        querkraft = auflagerkraft - belastung*x - if(einzellastlaenge == x) then write(*,*) "einzellast" else if(einzellastlaenge > x)then write(*,*)"0";
        print *, '  Q(x=',x,') = ', querkraft, 'kN'
    end do    
    print *, '- Momente:'
    do i = 0, 10
        x = stuetzlaenge*i/10;
        moment = belastung*stuetzlaenge*stuetzlaenge/2 - belastung*x*x/2 - if(einzellastlaenge == x) then write(*,*) "einzellast*einzellastlaenge";
        print *, '  M(x=',x,') = ', moment, 'kNm'
    end do

100 format(1X,A)

end program statik
```

**the errors:**

> 1                           Error: Line truncated at (1)
>   [-Werror=line-truncation]
>   main.f95:49:97:
>
> ```
>      moment = belastung*stuetzlaenge*stuetzlaenge/2 - belastung*x*x/2 - if(einzellastlaenge == x) then write(*,*) "einzellast*einzellastlaenge";           
>                     1
> ```
>
> Error:
>       Invalid character in name at (1)
>       main.f95:50:1:

Comment: First is to use the correct compiler if you already use foreign code (otgherwise you would know which language it is). Feel free to add a tag with the correct version of the language.

Comment: I am wondering about your inline `if` statements... What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Fun fact: you can use any compiler command from the GCC collection to compile any language supported. The correct frontend will be selected based on the source file. The command only determines the libraries linked and related details. I routinely compile C using gfortran and can perfectly imagine the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from those lines being syntactically incorrect, they are also too long. Either break them down using line continuation (`&`), or extend the number of considered columns per line. 
Assuming you are using `gfortran` (from the error messages), this is done using [`-ffree-line-length-0` or `-ffree-line-length-none`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html).